# shinymanager logout by click on a button

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to logout and auth screen to appear when the user clicks on a button.

```
credentials <- data.frame(
  user = "x", 
  password = "x"
)

library(shiny)
library(shinymanager)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$h2("My secure application"),
  actionButton("action_logout", "Logout!")
)

ui <- secure_app(ui)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  res_auth <- secure_server(
    check_credentials = check_credentials(credentials)
  )

  observeEvent(input$action_logout, {
    # logout
  }) 
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I found out that shinymanager's default logout button in the lower right corner has `id = ".shinymanager_logout"`, so I tried to call that with `session$sendCustomMessage(".shinymanager_logout", 1)`. That's probably a very naive way.

How can I logout the user with my custom logout button?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way to doing that is to reload the shiny session with `session$reload()`, so in your example:

```
observeEvent(input$action_logout, {
  session$reload()
})
```

But maybe we can implement something in the package, you can comment in this issue: https://github.com/datastorm-open/shinymanager/issues/7

Answer (score 0):

In the function `secure_server`, the the button `.shinymanager_logout` trigers this code:

```
observeEvent(session$input$.shinymanager_logout, {
  token <- getToken(session = session)
  logout_logs(token)
  .tok$remove(token)
  clearQueryString(session = session)
  session$reload()
}, ignoreInit = TRUE)
```

So, I suppose you can logout the user using your custom logout button by replacing `session$input$.shinymanager_logout` with you custom logout button id.